# Perforce : wanted to Multiline description

Tags: perforce

Hi I wanted to put multi line description using following command

```
p4 --field Description="MY CLN Header \\n my CLN complete description in two -three lines update " change -o |p4 change -i
```

Comment: And what happened?

Comment: and expected multiline text appeared as single line with \n

Comment: Do you issue this command in a Linux shell? If so, do this and copy-paste the output here: `echo $SHELL`

Answer (score 2):

If you can't convince your shell to pass the required linebreak and tab characters as part of the command line argument, try telling the `--field` option to append the second line to the first:

```
p4 --field Description="MY CLN Header" --field Description+="my CLN complete description in two -three lines update" change -o|p4 change -i
```

(edit) or, since that's buggy, you could do something like this using P4Perl:

```
$change = $p4->FetchChange();
$change->_Description( "MY CLN Header \n my CLN complete description in two -three lines update " );
$form = $p4->FormatChange( $change );
$p4->SaveChange( $form );
```

Comment: line is appended on same line.

Comment: Ah -- yeah, looks like there's a minor bug right here: https://swarm.workshop.perforce.com/projects/perforce_software-p4/files/2018-2/client/clientuserdbg.cc#228 It should append a `\n` if it's a multiline field.

Comment: oh I see I suggested a patch for this several months ago, lol: https://forums.perforce.com/index.php?/topic/5856-cmooand-line-adding-control-characters-to-descriptions/#entry23973

Comment: Write a script (e.g. in Perl or Python) to process the changelist form, or apply that patch to the CLI and recompile it with the fix.